# where is the Firefox DownThemAll userdata stored?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I want to export the list of file-names and corresponding information like URLs of the files I have downloaded using DownThemAll (DTA). But as far as I know, it doesn't have this feature.

So I want to know where is the DownThemAll userdata stored on Linux systems and on Windows systems?
I am using firefox 23 on Ubuntu/Windows-7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://bugs.downthemall.net/ticket/1368) answers your question.

In short:

> DownThemAll does not really store that information at all
>
> - dta_queue.sqlite does contain the queue information. It is an sqlite database file.
> - The queue table holds the actual information in the "item" column.
> - The "item" column has various properties encoded as json.
> - Within that json structure are the "fileName", "pathName" and "mask" fields along with other fields of interest.
> - The actual path is computed as needed from these values. It is currently not cached anywhere on disk as there really is no need for caching. The code that computes the function is located in branches/1.1.x/chrome/content/dta/manager.js@#L1546.

Granted, that bugreport is old by now, but I don't think DTA has changed significantly since.

Comment: Hi, Where is dta_queue.sqlite database stored on the disk? or if it is not stored on disk then where do I find the DTA js and json files on a Linux/Windows system?

Comment: In a GNU/Linux system, it's in `~/.mozilla/firefox/${profile}/dta_queue.sqlite`

Comment: In Windows, type %APPDATA% in your files browser, then look for >Mozilla >Firefox >Profiles... therein you will find the mysterious dta~.sqlite